# How to combine rows with a similar name but have different suffixes?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, netsuite

I've been rusty with my dataset programming. Ideally I want this done in a search in NetSuite and probably work with a formula or criteria, but if that's not possible, then I mainly would like get help with that via Python and see if I can make it work with it.

So I've got the following dataset:

```
| Name     | Description | Onhand   |
| -------- | ----------- | -------- |
| ItemA    | aaaa-bb     |   1      |
| ItemA-X  | aaaa-bb-x   |   3      |
| ItemA-Y  | aaaa-bb-y   |   1      |
| ItemA-Z  | aaaa-bb-z   |   2      |
| ItemB    | bbbb-00     |   0      |
| ItemB-X  | bbbb-00-x   |   3      |
| ItemB-Y  | bbbb-00-y   |   0      |
| ItemC-X  | cccc-01-x   |   2      |
```

So I've got a dataset that has similar names with different suffixes, what I want is to combine the rows with similar names, but with different suffixes with their Onhand values corresponding to different columns:

```
| Name     | Description | Available | Available-X | Available-Y | Available-Z |
| -------- | ----------- | --------- | ----------- | ----------- | ----------- |
| ItemA    | aaaa-bb     |   1       |   3         |   1         |   2         |
| ItemB    | bbbb-00     |   0       |   3         |   0         |   0         |
| ItemC-X  | cccc-01-x   |   0       |   2         |   0         |   0         |
```

Honestly, I was just thinking of manually iterating them and comparing rows, but is there a faster way in NumPy/Pandas maybe?

**EDIT:**
Made one mistake on my dataset. I do have certain rows that have hyphenated values at the end too, but aren't X/Y/Z. And only want to split into columns that have X/Y/Z. Those that don't have X/Y/Z at the end can have their values set at the first Available Column

```
| Name     | Description | Onhand   |
| -------- | ----------- | -------- |
| ItemA    | aaaa-bb     |   1      |
| ItemA-X  | aaaa-bb-x   |   3      |
| ItemA-Y  | aaaa-bb-y   |   1      |
| ItemA-Z  | aaaa-bb-z   |   2      |
| ItemB    | bbbb-00     |   0      |
| ItemB-X  | bbbb-00-x   |   3      |
| ItemB-Y  | bbbb-00-y   |   0      |
| ItemC-X  | cccc-01-x   |   2      |
| ItemD-D  | ddd-01-d    |   2      |
```

```
| Name     | Description | Available | Available-X | Available-Y | Available-Z |
| -------- | ----------- | --------- | ----------- | ----------- | ----------- |
| ItemA    | aaaa-bb     |   1       |   3         |   1         |   2         |
| ItemB    | bbbb-00     |   0       |   3         |   0         |   0         |
| ItemC-X  | cccc-01-x   |   0       |   2         |   0         |   0         |
| ItemD-D  | ddd-01-d    |   2       |   0         |   0         |   0         |
```

Answer (score 0):

With [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas), you can try this :

```
des = (
    df["Description"].str.extract(
        "(.+-.+)-.+", expand=False)
        .fillna(df["Description"])
)

piv_config = {
    "index": ["Name", "Description"],
    "columns": "Availability", "values": "Onhand"
}

out = (
    df["Name"].str.rsplit("-", expand=True).assign(
        Name= lambda x: x[0].where(x[0].duplicated(), df["Name"]),
        Availability= lambda x: x.pop(1).str.extract("([XYZ])", expand=False)
            .fillna("").radd("Available-").str.rstrip("-"),
        Description= lambda x: des.where(x[0].duplicated(), df["Description"]))
        .join(df["Onhand"]).pivot(**piv_config).fillna(0, downcast="infer")
        .reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

      Name Description  Available  Available-X  Available-Y  Available-Z
0    ItemA     aaaa-bb          1            3            1            2
1    ItemB     bbbb-00          0            3            0            0
2  ItemC-X   cccc-01-x          0            2            0            0
3  ItemD-D    ddd-01-d          2            0            0            0
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Works kinda. Just one problem.
On the event that for example when a row that has an "ItemD-D" for example occurs, and I only want -X -Y -Z and the original Available as the only new columns, how do I ignore ItemD-D from splitting? I have multiple occurrences in my dataset that has lots of hyphenated values, but I only want to get -X/-Y/-Z hyphens at the end of each name. Everything else can stay as is with their values placed in the Available column

Comment: You're welcome. Can you update the given example/output accordingly to reflect this configuration ?

Comment: Updated! Thanks so much for helping me out!

Comment: I updated my answer to handle that, can you check it out ?